# Asp.net Core on Docker - Cannot access index.html or /swagger/v1/swagger.json

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

I have a Web API with ASP.NET Core, everything looks good to me by using Visual Studio on Mac, I can see the swagger generated, like this
[image]
[image]

Next, I want to have build my web api as a docker container, I have a dockerfile like this[image], a have a docker image built and I can start my project using this command [image]

My API still working fine, but the issue I am asking for advices is why I cannot access the index.html any more, /swagger/v1/swagger.json neither, how to fix that?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your API working well and the only thing you can't access is swagger, I'd suspect that you've got a condition in Startup.cs to run swagger only in Development. Example below. Remove this condition to get swagger in Production (You're running the container in Production)

```
if(env.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
}
```